# Android studio buggy after upgrade to 16.10

Tags: android-studio

I recently upgraded from 16.04 LTS where my android studio was working fine to 16.10 but on trying to run my avd emulators, this is the error log i get back instead

```
Cannot launch AVD in emulator.
Output:
libGL error: unable to load driver: i965_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: i965
libGL error: unable to load driver: i965_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: i965
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
X Error of failed request:  GLXBadContext
  Major opcode of failed request:  155 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  6 (X_GLXIsDirect)
  Serial number of failed request:  55
  Current serial number in output stream:  54
libGL error: unable to load driver: i965_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: i965
libGL error: unable to load driver: i965_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: i965
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
X Error of failed request:  GLXBadContext
  Major opcode of failed request:  155 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed r
```

Comment: is android studio on this path `opt/android-studio`??

Comment: This happens for me on Ubuntu 17.04 also. @Arduino_Sentinel's answer fixed it.

Answer (score 48):

In the recent android studio updates, google use a `libstdc++` that is 
incompatible with the intel driver installed on the system

You first have to install the following packages if there not on the system 
`lib64stdc++6` and `mesa-utils`

```
sudo apt-get install lib64stdc++6 mesa-utils
```

Then symlink the libraries to the android sdk tools path

```
## For the /Sdk/tools path

cd ~/Android/Sdk/tools/lib64/libstdc++
# making a copy of the file
sudo mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.og
# symlink
sudo ln -s /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 ~/Android/Sdk/tools/lib64/libstdc++

## For the /Sdk/emulator path

cd ~/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/libstdc++
# making a copy of the file
sudo mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.og 
# symlink
sudo ln -s /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 ~/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/libstdc++
```

Comment: Folder was in `~/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/libstdc++` for me.

Answer (score 42):

I had also this problem on Ubuntu 17.04 and here's what I did.

Edit your `.profile` using your favorite text editor

```
atom ~/.profile
```

Append this at the end of the file

```
export ANDROID_EMULATOR_USE_SYSTEM_LIBS=1
```

[Source: Android SDK Environment Variable](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/variables.html)

Comment: the best solution

Comment: This didn't work on Ubuntu 17.10 with Android Studio 3.01. I just renamed the library folder ~/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/lib/libstdc++ and it worked.

Comment: Worked for me on Kubuntu 18.04. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 18):

Run emulator from terminal

```
emulator -use-system-libs -avd YOUR_VIRTUAL_DEVICE_NAME
```

Comment: Is there any way to make this the default, so I don't need to run it from a terminal?

Comment: @karora see jasperagrante's answer

Comment: @AltianoGerung yeah, since I already wrap Android Studio in a shell script I ended up setting the variable in there...

Answer (score 4):

another simple workaround is to rename the libstdc++ in the emulator folder in the Android sdk directory. It will fallback to the system libs (need to be installed).
That 'just worked' for me on Ubuntu 17.10.

Comment: Haha this is ridiculous!

Comment: What do you mean :)? I personally don't understand why Google ships it like this. The use-system-libs option didn't work for me, so it seems like a valid workaround, one just has to do it again when the emulator is updated.

Answer (score 2):

## Update the emulator.

```
Tools -> SDK Manager -> SDK Tools -> Android Emulator
```

[image]

This is a bug which is being fixed in 27.2.9.

> The Linux version of the Android Emulator is now built using a modern
>   Clang C++ toolchain. This change fixes the issue of the emulator
>   failing to start due to libGL and libstdc++ errors.

---

**FYI:** BTW manually creating symlinks is not a good idea.

Setting `ANDROID_EMULATOR_USE_SYSTEM_LIBS` is a better approach. However, that's also not necessary when you could just update the emulator.

Answer (score 1):

I switched the graphics acceleration from auto/hardware to software. The drivers that are causing this issue are only needed to use real hardware for graphics acceleration. Unless your working on a game or other graphics intensive software you don't really need this. This has to be done on each adv but stays set once done.

Answer (score -1):

This [link](https://en.proft.me/2016/05/13/fix-libgl-error-unable-load-driver-i965_driso/) help. I did modify the location of the libstdc++.so based on my Ubuntu 17.10 installation. The libstdc++.so file location was different. Search your computer for libstdc++.so

#### Ubuntu 17.10 and Android Studio 3.1

```
cd /opt/android-sdk/emulator/lib64/libstdc++
mv libstdc++.so.6{,.bak}
mv libstdc++.so.6.0.19{,.bak}
ln -s /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/libstdc++.so
```