# Steam not opening on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: steam

I'm trying to run Steam on my Ubuntu 18.04 after upgrading from 16.04 (it was running flawlessly there). The issue is, that it's not opening. When I try to execute command `steam` in the terminal, it returns this message:

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 18.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(0)
libGL error: unable to load driver: i965_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: i965
libGL error: unable to load driver: i965_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: i965
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

The only thing I understand from it is that a driver can't load properly, but I don't know what to do with that.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://askubuntu.com/questions/867081/android-studio-buggy-after-upgrade-to-16-10

Comment: go to https://askubuntu.com/questions/654566/steam-doesnt-start-libgl-error[1]
and and run from answer 1.

Answer (score 0):

These commands should fix it, thanks to The Intelligent Human,([Steam doesn't start. LibGL error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/654566/steam-doesnt-start-libgl-error)) and kisak-valve (https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux/issues/5249)

```
rm ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
rm ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
LD_PRELOAD='/usr/$LIB/libstdc++.so.6' LIBGL_DRI3_DISABLE=1 steam
```

Finally, run the command `steam` and it should launch and begin updating.